# Using one vuex module store in multiple sibling components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I have one global state with some modules.

now i have vue components for various parts of my page.

i have everything setup so `/foo` uses the `foo` store (this works).
the `created` method loads data from an API and writes it to the store

now i have `/foo/bar` as another (sibling) component, but it needs to access the same store as `/foo`, but i can't get it to work.

if i enter `/foo/bar/` in the URL, there is nothing in the store.
but if i switch to `/foo`, and then back to `/foo/bar`, the data is in the store and being output correctly

I've tried registering `/foo/bar` as a child, which seemed to have no effect (and actually it's not really a child, but just another page with the same data..)

I also tried

```
state: {
    ...mapState([
        'foo'
    )]
}
```

in `/foo/bar`, but that doesn't seem to be the right way either

what is the best practice to

1. load data from API on `created` on any of a specified set of pages
2. access said data on any of those pages (i.e. sharing the same store)

i've tried all day to find a solution, but it seems I didn't understand something.

thanks for your help :)

### EDIT

actually, while i read my question again, i think my whole problem is the data not being loaded (because the `created` method is not called). how can i make sure this happens on any page using the store and just once? i can't just write an api call in every `created` method, can i?

Comment: If you need global data for all pages in your application just do it wherever you define `const vue = new Vue({ })`

Comment: that's exactly the point: i don't need it *globally*, but just in a subset of pages. imagine 3 pages using store A and 3 different pages using store B. i want to separate those stores...

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think just to summarize your problem could be called like you're not being able to access the same state between two different componentes.

What I do normally is that I make an API call from one component inside the method `beforeMount`, that will guarantee that once my component is created, the data will be available to be used.

Furthermore, after calling the api, I update my state so after that I can call it from everywhere.

One thing that you have to take care with is which component is loaded first?

If A is B's parent, then you should load data inside A. 
However, if A and B are siblings, then you should load data inside both of them because you can access first either Component A or B, then you don't know when the data is going to be available. In that case, I would load the data in both of the components. 
Also, add cache to your server so you don't need to load the same data again.

For example:

State

```
{
  data: {}
}
```

Component A

```
export default {
  name: 'Batch',
  beforeMount() {
    this.getDataFromAPI();
  },
  methods: {
    // getDataFromAPI will store its return inside data with a mutation
    ...mapActions(['getDataFromAPI']),
    randomMethod() {
      // Now I can Use my state
      const data = this.$store.state.data;
    }
  }
};
```

Component B

```
export default {
  name: 'Batch',
  methods: {
    randomMethodB() {
      // If component A was loaded first than component B and A is B's parent, then the state will be accessible in the same manner and it should be populated
      const data = this.$store.state.data;
    }
  }
};
```

Actions

```
const getDataFromAPI = ({ commit }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 

  // Call server
  const data = await callServer();
  commit('updateMyStateWithData');
  resolve(data);

});

export default {
  getDataFromAPI
}
```

Mutations

```
const mutations = {
  updateMyStateWithData(state, newData) {
    state.data = newData;
  }
}

export default mutations;
```

Another thing that I do is to define getters, that way is a good approach to load data once, and inside the getter you update the data to return only the things that your UI needs.

I hope that it helps!

Comment: sounds reasonable.. but i didn't get how component B will "know" that A has already made an api call or if there is the need to load data "for the first time". can i do this with a getter? something like an api-singleton? i want to avoid unnecessary api-calls of course, but i didn't quite understand how the store will know that it's already present, or that it has to be loaded (because the component loading it was actually never even opened)

Comment: `how component B will "know" that A has already made an api cal` -> You can check something like: `Object.keys(this.$store.state.data) === 0` or `this.$store.state.data.length === 0` in case it's an array. 
A getter will only access data from your state once loaded, and when the state is updated, the getter will be updated too.
If you can access randomly from A or B, then load data only if the data inside the state is empty I guess